# What does the @ mean in the grafana metrics?

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

i have just started to deal with grafana and elastic. in the dokus i see things like @timestamp or @value again and again. Is that a variable that you set somewhere?

can this be used for any elasticsearch database? i connected elastic without metricbeats… and only get to the timestamp when i walk over an object. Means : object.timestamp

Answer (score 0):

@ is used in Logstash( part of Elastic stack) like @timestamp.  @timestamp variable is set as default, but you can change that and some other fields can be used instead of timestamp( you need a field that can be used as time or date for your graph to work). For example, if you have a time variable, you can use it instead of @timestamp by just typing 'time' in the text box of your query.

I don't know much about Logstash, but since they are both part of Elastic stack. I assume @ will be used in elastic database. Hope this helps a little bit.